# JavaScript Functions In Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Can you add JavaScript functions to .gs files and then run functions on Google Sheets?

The use case for me is to make use of Google's https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber to sweep through and sanitise some phone numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be possible but would require some manual work of creating files in the Script Editor and manually copying and pasting the code over.

I have had success doing this with other Javascript libraries in the past.

You will need basic Javascript skills, since you'll still need to write a bit of code to leverage the library once you have it moved over.  You could use a custom formula function or you could have a function that pulls in the relevant cells from the sheet and processes them before writing them out somewhere.

For custom spreadsheet formulas, see: 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

For processing sheet data within the script, see:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. Can now copy phone numbers from Excel into GS. Reformat using libphonenumber and copy back.

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Script is based on JavaScript, so yes, it's possible. See [Using open-source libraries in Apps Script](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2012/11/using-open-source-libraries-in-apps.html).